# make UIButton tap area larger

Tags: ios, uibutton, cgrect

I have a lot of buttons, but they are quite small, and I dont want to make them bigger, I just want to make tap area bigger. I tried

```
func makeInsets(button: UIButton) {
    button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: -40, left: -40, bottom: -40, right: -40)
}
```

but this make bigger only image. Any advices on this case?

Comment: you can't make the tap area for a button beyond its frame .

Comment: Thats what button is for!!! You can try touch began method!!

Comment: so only way is make frame of button bigger?

Comment: yes!!! Thats the only way

Comment: change the button's size to bigger...?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by making the button frame bigger and then adjust it with `EdgeInsets`:

1 Select your button;

2 Go to this menu and at "Edge" category;

[image]

3 Select "Content" and chose "Image";

[image]

4 Adjust "top" "bottom" "left" Right" insets to adjust image inside button

**For this to work Image must be added to button with "..setImage" and not "..setBackgroundImage"**

**If "Content" is selected it will modify both: Images and Text inside button**

It can also be done programatically but it's a little bit harder for not being able to see live modifications and you must calculate.

Hope it helps.

Update:

As an update to your question update you could try:

-change `-40` into `40` : this will make your button remain bigger and image inside will smaller in every side with 40 and it will answer to your question

- if you want to modify whole button (text + image) you whould use `btn.contentEdgeInsets` instead `btn.imageEdgeInsets` and set values

Comment: Thank you. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Make the frame of the button bigger, but change the view mode in interface builder to center the image, and not fill.  This keeps the image at the original size but the borders of your button extend invisibly beyond.